# Find string in multiple files

Tags: php, find

I need to check if $string exists in one of the files in a folder. Below is what I have, but it's obviously not working. What am I missing?

```
foreach (glob($path . 'foo/bar/*.*') as $file) {

  if (strpos(file_get_contents($file), $string) !== false) {
    //** found
  } else {
    //** not found
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work. Have you checked the path? (`print_r(glob($path . 'foo/bar/*.*'));` <- Check if your files are in this array)

Comment: data/user/*.* is empty, data/user/ prints the path - no files though - and yes, the folder is there, has files, and path is valid

Comment: Then your path is wrong, otherwise you should have files in the array. Please show us your file structure, where this code script is located and where the files are located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure all your files include an extension? You could try

```
glob($path . 'foo/bar/*')
```

and see if that works.

Also, if you're using Windows you should use a backslash (\) instead of a forward slash (/). You could use the DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR constant to let PHP automate it for you.

```
glob($path . 'foo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bar' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '*.*')
```

Are you also sure that $path ends with a slash?

Comment: Did some shuffling around and finally ended up with glob('./data/user/*') A shame I figured this myself, but I'll accept your answer nonetheless ;) Am on *nix alright, but some windozers may find DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR useful, thanks.